# Memtest86 reports same read speed / different write speed with single and dual channel ram. How?

Tags: memory, performance, benchmarking, memtest86

This is my old desktop pc with:

Intel i5-7400 / 16G+16G (Corsair CMK16GX4M1A2400C16 ) / GA-H110M-H mobo.

I did Passmark Memtest86 Ram Benchmark with single (16G) stick and double (16G+16G) sticks and got the following results:

== Single Stick ==
Write Speed: 7500 MB/s
Read Speed: 16000 MB/s

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHTlN.jpg

== Double Stick ==
Write Speed: 13000 MB/s
Read Speed: 16000 MB/s

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWipF.jpg

Interpreting the results, based on my knowledge, the double stick write speed is close to twice of single stick write speed because its double = dual channel ram over single = single channel ram.

But what confuses me is, how is the read speed similar in both setups. Either the single stick read speed should be lesser or the double stick read speed should be higher.

Isn't it ? Can somebody explain ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you certain you have the memory sticks in the right slots for dual channel to operate? Intel are [quite specific](https://superuser.com/questions/1623080/placing-memory-modules-in-gigabyte-z490m-1-0-motherboard/1623083#1623083) about what order you fill the slots.

Comment: @Mokubai there are only 2 slots on gigabyte GA-H110M-H. and i filled them both with identical corsair vengeance sticks

Comment: Can you run [CPU-z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and see what it says on the memory tab? Where the following image says "Single" you should see "Dual": https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpiha.png Is there maybe some setting in your BIOS that is disabling dual channel?

Answer (score 0):

Memtest might only be using one core. Try running a dedicated memory benchmark that uses multiple cores or a "Stream" benchmark.

https://developer.amd.com/spack/stream-benchmark/

While you might have more memory bandwidth available, you might not be able to utilize it with only a single threaded application.

If the issue persists ensure you have the correct settings in your bios for dual channel operation. (Such as interleaving)

EDIT: On windows PassMark has a memory benchmark that should work
https://www.passmark.com/products/performancetest/pt_advmem.php